# Android | Repeating alarm clock

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

I have an alarm clock app. I made it using the AlarmManager class. But I made only a single alarm, and I need an alarm that will be repeated every day and on the days of the week.

I want :  1. An every day alarm clock
2. An alarm clock that works on selected days of week.

It is my code from a single alarm (The code works good):

```
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
                        long startUpTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                        if (System.currentTimeInMillis() > startUpTime) {
                            startUpTime = startUpTime + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
                            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo =
                                    new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(startUpTime, getClockInfo());
                            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
                        } else {
                            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo =
                                    new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(alarm.timeInMillis, getClockInfo());
                            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
                        }
```

My code from every day alarm (The code does not work exactly, when I set alarm at 6:40 it works at 7:00):

```
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
                        long startUpTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                         if (System.currentTimeInMillis() > startUpTime) {
                            startUpTime = startUpTime + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    startUpTime,
                                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                    pendingIntent);
                        } else {
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    startUpTime,
                                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                    pendingIntent);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look here may can help you it works perfect in my app . I have done with kotlin you there t=are some syntax difference but logics are same.

```
private fun setAlarm1() {
        var calender: Calendar
      calender = Calendar.getInstance()
                    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, PUT_YOUR_ALARM HOUR)
                    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, PUT_YOUR_ALARM MINUTE)
                    calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                val thuReq: Long = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis + 1
                var reqReqCode = thuReq.toInt()
                if (calender.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
                }
                val alarmTimeMilsec = calender.timeInMillis
                val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqReqCode, intent, 0)
        
                alarmManager.setRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calender.timeInMillis,
                   24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,// or AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
                    pendingIntent
                )
```

for more help go to this link https://github.com/Niajnm/Android-RandomUser-Alarm-Trigger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/randomuser/AlarmClock/AlarmCreateActivity.kt
I made a app multi functional medicine alarm clock. it may help you

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `setRepeating()` works not exactly. I want the alarm to work at 7:00 AM not at 7:30.